# How to perform dot product on each row of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dot-product

I have the following data.table :

```
#    id      b          c           d
# 1: 1 -0.25174915 -0.2130797 -0.67909764
# 2: 2 -0.35569766  0.6014930  0.35201386
# 3: 3 -0.31600957  0.4398968 -1.15475814
# 4: 4 -0.54113762 -2.3497952  0.64503654
# 5: 5  0.11227873  0.0233775 -0.96891456
# 6: 6  1.24077566 -1.2843439  1.98883516
# 7: 7 -0.23819626  0.9950835 -0.17279980
# 8: 8  1.49353589  0.3067897 -0.02592004
# 9: 9  0.01033722 -0.5967766 -0.28536224
```

and I would like to make a dot product with each row with the following matrix obtained from a *PCA$rotation matrix == `coefs`*:

```
coefs 
#     PC1   PC2    PC3
#var1 x1    x2     x3
#var2 y1    y2     y3
#var3 z1    z2     z3
```

in order to obtain a new column in my data.table as this:

```
#    id      b          c           d        results
# 1: 1 -0.25174915 -0.2130797 -0.67909764    x1*-0.25174915 + y1*-0.2130797 +z1*-0.67909764 + x2*-0.25174915 + y2*-0.2130797 + z2*-0.67909764 +x3*-0.25174915 + y3*-0.2130797 + z3*-0.67909764
# 2: 2 -0.35569766  0.6014930  0.35201386    x1*-0.35569766 + y1*0.6014930 +z1*0.35201386 + x2*-0.35569766 + y2*0.6014930  + z2*0.35201386 +x3*-0.35569766 + y3*0.6014930  + z3*0.35201386
# 3: 3 -0.31600957  0.4398968 -1.15475814
# 4: 4 -0.54113762 -2.3497952  0.64503654
# 5: 5  0.11227873  0.0233775 -0.96891456
# 6: 6  1.24077566 -1.2843439  1.98883516
# 7: 7 -0.23819626  0.9950835 -0.17279980
# 8: 8  1.49353589  0.3067897 -0.02592004
# 9: 9  0.01033722 -0.5967766 -0.28536224
```

Comment: another option is `rowSums(as.matrix(df) %*% coefs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to do `x*coefs` for each row `x`, then take the sum. The vector `x` will be multiplied column-wise with `coefs` and will be recycled, which matches the formula you give.

```
df$results <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) sum(x*coefs))
```